# How do I list my qualifications from another country on my CV?

Tags: job-search

I am living in Missouri USA. I undertook my studies in India and hold a bachelor degree in Computer Application and an incomplete master degree in Computer Application.

How can I apply for jobs in the US with my degrees attained in India?

Comment: I have taken the liberty of cleaning up the spelling and grammer in your question, and making the subject more indicative of your question.  Please let me know if I have changed your original intent.

Comment: no different than if you were applying for a job in India

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** It really is no different from listing any qualification(s).

Just include it the same way you do if you happened to have your degree from the US or any other institution.  State your qualifications and institution in your CV, and any skills or experience that you have.

As to how a foreign-obtained degree is perceived by prospective employers, that's entirely company and hiring manager specific.

Answer (score 1):

I would add that in this age when verification of credentials by employers is standard practice (as in any age) honesty is important.

So try to be factually accurate with all of your credentials: provide exact university names, dates attended or date when degree was earned, and exact title of your degree / major field.

Even if it may sound different from typical US degrees ("Computer Science" vs. "Computer Application"), it is better to be forefront and let the employer figure out how to handle that, than take the editing in your own hands and come across as bending the truth here and there.

So I encourage you to honestly list your exact qualifications and stand by them with confidence. If you have skills, there will be a company with a job out there, where your skills will be a good fit. Good luck and thanks for the question!

Comment: As someone with a humble and kinda unknown degree in Programming, what I did was to add a link to the University website in my LinkedIn profile, which shows a brief description, goals, and all the legal details that prove it's 100% legit. If they still don't believe, well, they are free call the Ministry of Education and ask.